# SQLite: simple SQL - where in timestamp field

Tags: sqlite, date, time

I have a table with timestamp field call EVENT_TS (so it's stored as GMT time stamp)

I want to a query that would retrieve the records based on EVENT_TS, and query only returns today's result.

Here is what record looks at:

```
EVENT_DESC | EVENT_TS
-----------+--------------------
event1     | 2011-11-14 11:22:00
event2     | 2011-11-11 12:22:00
```

SO if today is Nov 14, I want it to return only today's event, which is event1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick (assuming that your system timezone is properly configured):

```
select *
from your_table
where date(event_ts, 'localtime') = date(current_timestamp, 'localtime')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is sql server:

```
select * from event
where convert(varchar(10),event_ts ,101) = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the type of that field is TEXT (SQLite can store date as TEXT, INTEGER, or REAL):

```
 SELECT * FROM Event WHERE Event_TS LIKE '2011-11-14%'
```

This query will be able to use and index on Event_TS if you've created one.